# Rails Group Articles by Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I can't seem to figure out why I can't group articles by category name. I have a categories table and an articles table which is joined through feeds. Below is an example of what I'm looking to accomplish.

example:

```
Sports
  article 1
  article 2
  article 3
Food
  article 1
  article 2
Music
  article 1
  article 2
```

Here are the associations:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :feeds
  has_many :articles, through: :feeds
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_id, :name, :source, :url, :category_id

  belongs_to :category
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessible :guid, :name, :published_at, :summary, :url, :feed_id

  belongs_to :feed
end
```

In articles controller I have this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    @article_list = @articles.group_by { |t| t.category.name }
  end
end
```

In Articles view:

```
<% @article_list.each do |category, article_items| %>
  <%= category %>   
  <% article_items.each do |article_item| %>
    <% article_item.name%>         
  <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why not iterate over the categories instead, and grab the articles from each category as you go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to develop the association between `Article` and `Category` in order to do the `group_by` as you have it defined right now.  You can use a `has_one :through` to solve this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :feeds
  has_many :articles, through: :feeds
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_id, :name, :source, :url, :category_id

  belongs_to :category
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessible :guid, :name, :published_at, :summary, :url, :feed_id

  belongs_to :feed
  has_one :category, :through => :feed
end
```

Once you have the above `has_one :category, :through => :feed`, you'll be able to do `@article.category`, or more specifically, `@article_list = @articles.group_by { |t| t.category.name }` successfully.

You will also need to update your view, as you're missing an `=`:

```
<% @article_list.each do |category, article_items| %>
  <%= category %>   
  <% article_items.each do |article_item| %>
    <%= article_item.name %>       # missing here  
  <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: In the view it seems to only show one category name with no articles listed. I'm not sure if my query is wrong in the controller or I'm not looping correctly in the view.

Comment: do you know how to limit the articles by category say to 5 results per category? I tried Article.all.limit(5) but its wrong because it will only pull 5 records from the database and not display other categories.

Comment: Sure - in your view, you could do: `article_items.last(5).each` - I'd recommend trying to do it in your controller.